# Какие способы эмуляции клавиш вы знаете?

Tags: c++, linux

Доброе время суток!
Хотелось бы знать, какие способы существуют и как реализовать в Eclipse C++ под Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через XSendEvent
http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/events.html